# Prove that multiplying an elementary matrix to a matrix can produce the same effect as an elementary row operation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Elementary row operations:**

1) Interchange any two rows of the matrix

2) Multiply every entry of some row of the matrix by the same nonzero scalar

3) Add a multiple of one row of the matrix to another row

**Elementary Matrix:**

An $n\times n$ matrix that is produced by performing exactly one elementary row operation on an $n\times n$ identity matrix.

**The other matrix in the multiplication has a dimension of $n\times m$.**

e.g. Multiply the first matrix to the second matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}     
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
Output:
  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        5 & 7 & 9 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Artin's Algebra text book. The first chapter has a discussion on elementary matrices as far as I can recall.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at a conceptual proof.

If it's true that a row operation can be performed by multiplying by some matrix $ M$, then $ M = M I $ is the matrix you get by performing the row operation on the identity matrix.

The only question is, can an elementary row operation be performed by multiplying by some matrix $ M $.

The answeris yes: A row operation takes a matrix $ A $ as input and applies the same linear transformation $ T $ to each column of $ A $.  This is the same as multiplying each column of $ A $ by $ M $, where $ M$ is the matrix that represents $ T$. And that's the same as multiplying $ A $ by $ M $.